# Why the data in the database appears in different order than the order in which data appears in the array?

Tags: node.js

I have an array like:

```
let dataArray=["abc","xyz","pqr", ...........]
```

let's say the size of the dataArray is 10000.

Now I want to save each data in the array as a `post` in the database.
Here is the code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
  const post = new Post({
    title: dataArray[i],
  });

  post
    .save()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log('Post has been saved: ');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

When the above code is executed I could see all the data of the array appear in the database `but in a different order`.

For example:
According to the array, `abc` should appear first then `xyz` and then `pqr` but when I view the database I see a post with the title `xyz` appear first then `abc` then `pqr`  [the order shown is just for explanation purpose every time I see a random order].

Please guide me on why data appear out of order and how it could be resolved. Also let me know if more information is required.

Comment: What is `Post`? What does `post.save()` do? What database are you using? Usually there isn't an "order" in database records. It is up to how you sort the retrieved records when you do query. If you want to preserve the array order, you probably need to store each record with the index, and sort the query result by the index.

Comment: I am using MongoDB as the database. Post is a mongoose model.

Comment: You have promise race in your's for loop. Check https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/insertMany/ for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoDB I think it keeps the order of the inserted elements, but it is better to add a field like `createdAt` to store the insertion date and you can use it later for sorting the data.

Comment: I was wondering since the ``for loop`` will execute very fast, will there be any difference in the ``createdAt`` field of the posts so that I could sort them. What if all the ``createdAt`` value is the same for all the posts?

Comment: MongoDB store the milliseconds so I think it is not going to happen frequently,
I remembered another thing, the ObjectId created by mongo keeps the order, it uses a timestamp value + random bytes for that